# EF Core conditional include

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a company entity with a one to many relationship to order entities.

An order can be anonymous, in which case the related company should not be loaded when querying the orders.

The current format creates an IQueryable and then adds filters to it as follows:

```
IQueryable<Order> queryable = ...
...
if (includeCompany is not null and true)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Include(o => o.Company);
    }

if (includeAddress is not null and true)
...
```

Can I condition the include to use the order's isAnonymous bool in a single query, as to only include the company entity for the orders that are not anonymous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, no. Filtered `Include` can't be applied to reference navigation properties, only collections.

You'll have to resort to an ugly work-around:

```cs
context.Orders.Select(o => new 
{ 
    o, 
    Company = o.Order.IsAnonymous
        ? null
        : o.Company
})
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => x.o)
```

Now the non-anonymous orders will have `Company` reference because EF populates them by *relationship fixup*.

`AsEnumerable` causes EF to build the entire anonymous type. Without it, the final `Select` is part of the expression and EF concludes that the companies can be ignored entirely because it doesn't "see" them in the end result.

Comment: Given the fact that (for obvious DRY reasons) the internal implementation of every related data loading "out-of-the-box" method relies on/uses in one way or another the navigation fixup, I wouldn't consider it "ugly", just annoying that it's not provided by the framework. But if it was, the materializing enumerator would do pretty much the same as shown here, just hiding it from outside.

Answer (score 1):

sure, `queryable = queryable.Include(o => o.Company).where(o => o.isAnonymous);`

queryable is **IQueryable**,You can add conditions And there was no access to the database.

Comment: This will not work, as it will only return the orders that match the where condition. What I want to do is return all orders, but only include the related company for the ones that are not anonymous.